# Importing sliding menu library for Android application development

Tags: android, menubar, sliding

I'm new to Android development and I would like to build a sliding menu...and I found the following lib:

https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation

they have very detailed guide... e.g. where to add code in the layouts and menu and stuff....

I've add all the codes they mentioned.. but still the sliding menu does not work...

I think I have to import their library into my project? How can I do it?

Download the file from their website /library/src/com/devspark/sidenavigation/ and import to my project's libs file?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used that particular library, but in general, to import it, once you download the file and extract it to a given destination, all you have to do (if you're using Eclipse) is file>import>Android>Existing Android into Workspace, and select that library location. And that's about it, to use it in your projects go to properties>Android and add the new library. I hope this helped!